# Decorating and Customisation Tools

Tags: java, android, jquery, ios

I want to develop a Customisation Tools which will provide user to add images and Text at specific location according to design.
Text colour  and font style is same as design.
There are some online website which are doing such things. I want to create such tools for mobile application android and iPhone. There are links of personalisation 
http://www.thatsmypan.com/store/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=65_105&products_id=361

http://www.bakerdays.com/cakes/954/personalise-text/reference/249243

How can a start developing for android and iPhone.I need some Help on that.